# Extract value from repeated xml tags in unix

Tags: xml, unix

I have sample xml below, I would like to extract values from the tags for example value=3. Since there are repeated tags I am finding challenge to do this in unix.

```
<Request>
<Destination>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
            <key>a</key>
            <value>1</value>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <key>b</key>
            <value>2</value>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <key>c</key>
            <value>3</value>
        </Parameter>
    </Parameters>
    <Proxy>
        <Destination>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter>
                    <key>a</key>
                    <value>1</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter>
                    <key>b</key>
                    <value>2</value>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter>
                    <key>c</key>
                    <value>3</value>
                </Parameter>
            </Parameters>
        </Destination>
    </Proxy>
</Destination>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is more compact to use  XQuery/XPath 3 (e.g. in my [implementation](http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html)) than XSLT.  Depending what you mean by "extract values", you can do  one of these:

```
xidel req.xml  --extract '//value'
```

to get all values

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

or with a prefix:

```
xidel req.xml  -e '//value/("value="||.)'
```

to get

```
value=1
value=2
value=3
value=1
value=2
value=3
```

To get all keys with a certain value:

```
xidel req.xml  -e '//*[value="3"]/key'

c
c
```

Or all values with a certain key:

```
xidel req.xml  -e '//*[key="b"]/value'

2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a command line XSLT processor like 'xsltproc' or 'xalan' and parse your .xml file using a .xsl stylesheet. Here's a stylesheet which refers to your sample xml data.

I am assuming there is an end tag corresponding to 'Request' at the end of your file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0">
  <xsl:output method = "text"/>
  <xsl:template match = "Request">
    <xsl:for-each select = "Destination/Parameters/Parameter">
        <xsl:text>value=<xsl:value-of select = "@value"/>
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:template match = "Proxy">
        <xsl:for-each select = "Destination/Parameters/Parameter">
            <xsl:text>value=<xsl:value-of select = "@value"/>
            </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig; 

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'your_xml_file' );

print $_ -> text,"\n" for $twig -> findnodes('//value');
```

Which reduces to a one liner:

```
perl -MXML::Twig -e 'print $_ -> text,"\n" for XML::Twig -> parse ( do { local $/;<> }  )-> findnodes('//value')' your_file.xml
```

If you want to get a bit more complicated with it, you can use `xpath` expressions to find particular things:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig; 

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'your_file.xml' ); 

foreach my $node ( $twig -> findnodes('//value[string()="3"]/../') ) {
   print $node -> first_child_text('key'),"\n";
}
```